# Error when bq ls command is used in VPC-SC environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

I have installed VPC-SC in GCP.

I got a VPC-SC error when I run the bq ls command in the cloud shell.

How can I resolve this?

I'm guessing that CloudShell is another GCP project.

Execute command:

```
bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=asia-northeast1 --filter='dataSourceIds:scheduled_query'
```

Error message:

```
Request is prohibited by organization's policy. vpcServiceControlsUniqueIdentifier:
```

ViolationReason:

```
RESOURCES_NOT_IN_SAME_SERVICE_PERIMETER
```